# Yii, Sort and column name in CsqlDataProvider

Tags: php, yii

I had trying to use cgridview with csqldataprovider.

1. my sql query takes data from different tables. I had used alias in query. So in gridview when i click on header value, it takes column name for sorting. i.e, `column name =  Track` it will create query with `... order by Track` but actually it should create `...order by t.trackname`.
2. To add more complexity i have column name in table as table name. E.g In same db with table name `Store` and col name `trackid`   i have another table in same db with table name `trackid`.
3. I had checked [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044681/yii-cgridview-sorting-with-csqldataprovider). Here in cgridview when I specify my column attribute it is not becoming sort-able (no anchor tags). Without column attribute it is sort-able.

In controller file,

```
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
        'totalItemCount'=>$count,
        'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'caseid DESC',
            'attributes'=>array(
             'caseid',
             'trackid',
             'status',
            ),
        ),
        ));
```

In view file,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
'columns'=>array(
    array('header'=>'Case','name'=>'Case','value'=>'$data[caseid]'),
    array('header'=>'Track','name'=>'Track','value'=>'$data[trackid]'),
    array('header'=>'Status','name'=>'Status','value'=>'$data[status]'),
),
```

Comment: can you show your `$query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `name` for each column of `CGridView` correctly. In your sample code it is incorrect, you have used `'name'=>'Case'` whereas it should be `'name'=>'caseid'` , i.e the value of `name` should be the **exact** value of the **alias** you specify in your sql.

Update:

1. Also note that incase you are not doing any formatting, or modifying the value retrieved from db, you do not need the `value` attribute. The `name` attribute will take care of getting the correct value from the db result set. The `header` will take care of displaying the column header name, which in your case is `Case`.

   Example:

   ```
   'columns'=>array(
       array('header'=>'Case','name'=>'caseid'), // 'value'=>'$data[caseid]'),
       array('header'=>'Track','name'=>'trackid'), // 'value'=>'$data[trackid]'),
       array('header'=>'Status','name'=>'status'), // 'value'=>'$data[status]'),
   ),
   ```
2. To handle situations 1 and 2 use alias(es) in your sql, and use those aliases' values in `sort`'s `attributes` array, and also in `name`.

   Sql example:

   ```
   select t.trackname as some_alias ...
   ```

   Dataprovider:

   ```
   'sort'=>array(
       'attributes'=>array(
           'some_alias',
           // ... more attributes ...
       ),
       // ... more options ...
   ),
   ```

   CGridView:

   ```
   'columns'=>array(
       array(
           'header'=>'Some Header Name',
           'name'=>'some_alias',
           'value'=>'$data["some_alias"]' // as mentioned above this is unnecessary if you are not modifying the value
       )
   )
   ```

   So when you sort, queries generated will be like : `order by some_alias`, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: this should solve your problem. do comment and lemme know how it works out.